# Cell of an array as an argument

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a nested array `someField[10][10]`, is there a way I can parse a cell from this array into a method, not just it's value. For example, I want to find summ of some presice cell and preeceding cell, can I get it like `sumMethod(someField[5][5])`. Or is there a way to do that at all?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your method needs to accept a 2D array and 2 indices.

Comment: So anyway it should have at least 3 parameters?

Comment: Yes pass a pointer to that cell

Comment: @JohnnyB.Goode Do you want to create a function to accept Array 2D?

Comment: @JohnnyB.Goode Yes. Is there any reason why you _don't_ want to do this?

Comment: @VidorVistrom what do you mean by cell pointer?

Comment: @Sweeper Just thought there's a way to use a cell itself but now I kind of understand how it should look)

Comment: my bad.. I misread the question with a C tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method has to accept a 2D array and 2 indices, otherwise only the value will be passed:

```
public void foo(int[][] array, int row, int column) {
    // you can access the cell's value by array[row][column]
    // you can also access adjacent cells such as array[row + 1][column]
}

public void foo(int value) {
    // here you only have access to the cell's value.
}
```

There is no "pointer" in Java that you can use to do arithmetic with.